# Implement signature based method in WAF

Tags: security, sql-injection, firewall

I wanna write a [WAF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall) which detects attacks with `signature-based` method. for example, for SQL injection, I collect a blacklist contains words such "select", "drop" and etc. when an attacker inputs these strings to query field, then the attack is detected.  Now, my question is how to separate these words from valid inputs that a regular user enters (such his username contains "select" word)? (Note that this is a [WAF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall) and I don't know what are the fields in the web app to check the best security and write a specific code for every field. I can just check common security and the rest must check by developers of the web app).

Answer (score 0):

There is no use for WAF in regard of SQL injection. Because

- There will be too much false positives that will be driving users mad. If such a silly approach were used on this site of Stack Overflow, you were just unable to post your question.
- Like any other black-listing based approach it will be **always incomplete** and thus will not offer 100% protection
- There are specific measures to prevent an SQL injection that offer 100% protection

Comment: Tnx, but what about for xss attack?

Comment: So what attacks could be cover by a waf?